# Word describing a specific kind of movement

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word or expression (if it exists) describing the movement that a plate makes when you lift from two nearby points of the edge, and then you release one a bit before the other. It looks like a rotation, but it is not.

When this movement is done with the hips, apparently it is called a hip roll: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s5Btyc_io4U

However, none of the definitions of "roll", such as "move in a particular direction by turning over and over on an axis" seem to fit the movement I describe.

The closest I can come up is rotational wave but it sounds very technical and I am trying to use this word in a literary context.

Comment: If I can offer some clarification, do you mean that the wave is going around the plate though the plate itself is not turning/rotating? I believe Feynman described this as a game people were playing in the cafeteria. He found it had some interesting math behind it.. One term to look up is *Precessing*  as a gyroscope does.

Comment: @Elliot The Feynman anecdote was what immediately came to mind for me as well. Along with precession, nutation might be worth checking out.

Comment: @user888379 Bravo *Nutation* is the word I could not pull up. As for Feynman, I'm glad for the company. Great minds think alike, stuck here in our basements.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to use this word in a literary context.

The normal verb used for this in everyday conversation is [**wobble**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wobble):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1 a** : to move or proceed with an irregular rocking or staggering motion or unsteadily and clumsily from side to side
>        // The vase *wobbled* but didn't fall over.
>        // The boy was *wobbling* along on his bicycle.

In terms of what's being described in the question, the following could be used:

> After I let go of the plate, it *wobbled* on the table until finally coming to rest.

---

From [*As You Wish*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=6-IZJPiHzNwC&pg=PA11&dq=%22plate%20wobbled%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSt-Db9rPqAhWlTt8KHairB6IQ6AEwBHoECCcQAg#v=onepage&q=%22plate%20wobbled%22&f=false) by Gabi Stevens:

> She expelled her breath, and with the rush of air, the plate wobbled and crashed to the floor.

From [*Marie Tanglehair*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=KCHd6W7N1QEC&q=%22plate%20wobbled%22&dq=%22plate%20wobbled%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSt-Db9rPqAhWlTt8KHairB6IQ6AEwHXoECFIQAg) by Dorothy Heiderstadt:

> The cake plate wobbled, and a lean brown hand caught and steadied it for her.

From [*The Little Book of Thinking Big*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=JtCSBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA81&dq=%22plate%20wobbled%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSt-Db9rPqAhWlTt8KHairB6IQ6AEwBnoECC4QAg#v=onepage&q=%22plate%20wobbled%22&f=false) by Robert Newton:

> In other words, when the plate was spinning slowly the plate wobbled at a rate exactly half of the rotation.

Comment: +1 That's what I thought too, then I saw you beat me to it :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would characterize the motion of the plate as a **gyration**. From M-W:

> **[gyrate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gyrating)**: to oscillate with or as if with a circular or spiral motion

The gyration is *damped* in that its amplitude decreases every cycle or period. It would work in a literary context.

Answer (score 0):

There is an exact word for this.

**Nutation** (from Latin nūtātiō, "nodding, swaying") is a rocking, swaying, or nodding motion in the axis of rotation of a largely axially symmetric object.

See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nutation